# Battery configuration for inverter?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, inverter

I have a PC with a 280 W PSU.

I am thinking about buying an inverter but I am confused.

I have an inverter which requires 36 VDC. Will it work if I add 3 12 V, 50 Ah batteries in series? Or shall I buy a new 12 V unit, with a 12 V, 100 Ah battery?

Also if I use 3 car batteries instead, will it make any difference?

Comment: RTFM read the fine manual a APS3636VR
Voltage compatibility: 12 VDC to 36V

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three car batteries (or other 12v 50Ah batteries) in series would make an ideal battery to supply a 36v input inverter.

Three 12v batteries of 50Ah store 50% more energy (run time into the same end load) than a single 12v battery of 100Ah.

An inverter you have will cost you rather less than one you have to buy.

A 12v input inverter will not be more efficient than a 36v input inverter, and will need thicker wires to supply it.